# How to delete a line which starts with a * using regex in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am currently using regex in R to delete a line which starts with a * such as:

```
* Wikipedia started from the public domain version reprinted by the [http://www.ccel.org/ Christian Classics Ethereal Library].  
* James William Richard (1898). From [[Internet Archive]].
* [http://www.melanchthon.de/e/ The Phillip Melanchthon Quinquennial]
```

And I tried to use function *gsub* and regex expression like:

```
gsub("^[\\*]+[\\s\\[A-Za-z,;'\"\\s]+[.?!\\]]$","",tex1)
```

But nothing happened. Could you please help me to figure out the problem with this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a line which starts with `*`

```
sub("(?m)^\\*.*\n?", "", x, perl=T)
```

Comment: How actually the contents look like?

Comment: try with multiline modifer.

Comment: Thx, now it works! But I am not very clear about the meaning of ?m.  According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html, ?m means "multi-line mode" , which makes the caret and dollar match at the start and end of each line in the subject string.  My question is why without ?m everything is unchanged? Is that related to my string?

Comment: because of the anchors used in the regex. If we use anchors, and the input contain newline chars, we must special the m modifier or s modifier .

Comment: @hui stolen from google images. Additionally I added a cap given by SO.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a vector of strings `v`, it is better to search if one of the element of the vector contains the motif you are looking for, so, you need rather `grepl` than `gsub`.

You can do:

```
v <- c("hello", "*hi", "world")
v[!grepl("^\\*", v)] # looks for the elements that begins with * and negates the result
#[1] "hello" "world"
```